# Throw 409 CONFLICT if data is coming from Cache - @Cachable in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, ehcache, idempotent

I have implemented caching using spring boot and ehcache. My scenario is about implementing idempotency key for POST method and for that I have created a cache based on idempotency key with @Cacheable annotation. What I want to do is return 409 CONFLICT if cache is present for a given the idempotency key.
I have following code in handler class which sends response to a Controller class.

```
@Cacheable(value="myCache", key="#idempotencyKey")
public DAO createRecord(String userID, String idempotencyKey) {
// database call
return new DAO();
}
```

What I want to do here is somehow find if the response I am receiving in Controller class is coming from cache. If it is coming from cache then throw 409 CONFLICT by wrapping it in ResponseEntity.

Request for a response as I am stuck at this.